# Why are my matrix values disappearing in C?

Tags: arrays, c, matrix, ascii, cellular-automata

I am attempting to make a simple 2D sand simulation using basic cellular automata concepts (for more information watch: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VLZjd_Y1gJ8) and display it in the console but for some reason random particles appear near the bottom line of the matrix and there is a lot of chaos if you modify the matrix in the slightest(e.g. if you draw a line across horizontally in the middle or a random point somewhere low it will appear completely different), I believe this could be due to an error in my in bounds check `if(grid[y][x] <= sizeY && grid[y][x] <=sizeX)` but I am not sure.

Code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#ifdef __unix__
# include <unistd.h>
#elif defined _WIN32
# include <windows.h>
#define sleep(x) Sleep(1000 * (x))
#endif

int sizeX = 20;
int sizeY = 20;
int alive = 1;
int dead = 0;

int grid[20][20] = {{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}};

int drawScreen(int x, int y) {
  system("cls"); // Clear screen
  for (x = 0; x <= sizeX; x++) {
    printf("\n");
    for (y = 0; y <= sizeY; y++) {
      if (grid[x][y] == alive) {
        printf("@");
      } else {
        printf(" ");
      }
    }
  }
}

int sand(int grid[sizeX][sizeY], int x, int y) {
  if (grid[y + 1][x] == dead) {
    grid[y][x] = dead;
    grid[y + 1][x] = alive;
  } else if (grid[y + 1][x - 1] == dead) {
    grid[y][x] = dead;
    grid[y + 1][x - 1] = alive;
  } else if (grid[y + 1][x + 1] == dead) {
    grid[y][x] = dead;
    grid[y + 1][x + 1] = alive;
  }
}

int main(void) {
  int x, y, iterations;

  for (iterations = 0; iterations < 1000; iterations++) {
    for (y = sizeY - 1; y >= 0; y--) {
      for (x = sizeX - 1; x >= 0; x--) {
        if (grid[y][x] == alive) {
          if (grid[y + 1][x] <= sizeY && grid[y][x + 1] <= sizeX) { // Bounds
            sand(grid, x, y);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    drawScreen(x, y);
  }
}
```

Comment: On a few unrelated notes: `#include<conio.h>` is attempting to include what used to be a DOS specific header files, still available in Windows. It's not available in Linux or on macOS, and isn't usually needed at all. Also, `system("cls")` is very Windows-specific and won't work on Linux or macOS. You should try to avoid these things when attempting to be platform independent.

Comment: You should avoid using globals unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: As for your problems, you start out with `x` and `y` equal to `sizeX` and `sizeY`. That means both `x` and `y` will be *out of bounds* immediately. And `x+1` and `y+1` even more so. Also when `x` and `y` are both equal to `0`, `x-1` and `y-1` will be out of bounds again. All this out-of-bounds access will lead to *undefined behavior*, making your program ill-formed.

Comment: Springboarding off previous comment, the first evidence during run-time that array out of bounds occurs is here:  `if(grid[y][x] == alive){`  where the message on my machine is:  `FATAL RUN-TIME ERROR:   "exec.c", line 74, col 17, thread id 4308:   Dereference of out-of-bounds pointer: 81 bytes (21 elements) past end of array.`

Comment: @Some programmer dude Thanks for your advice on your first comment but I am using windows so I do not belive that is the source of the problem, as for you second comment, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Your issues boil down to undefined behavior reading array memory out of bounds.

Arrays are zero-indexed, so loops should run `x < sizeX`, not `x <= sizeX`.

```c
if (grid[y + 1][x] <= size_y && grid[y][x + 1] <= size_x) { // Bounds
```

isn't a good bounds check because it's testing the `grid` values, not `y` and `x`. You probably meant to test `y < size_y - 1` and `x < size_x - 1`.

Now, the bounds check should be precise. If a cell is on the right side, we should still potentially move it downward or to the left, but skip the `x + 1` rightward check/move. Same for other bounds. With this in mind, I'd bake the bounds checks into the `sand()` function (since functions are actions, I'd rename this as `simulate_sand()`).

You've also switched `grid[y][x]` to `grid[x][y]` in your `drawScreen()` function. Since your grid has the same height and width, it doesn't cause any problems, but if they weren't the same, this would be out of bounds.

You can compile with `gcc -Wall -ggdb3 your_file.c` and then use `valgrind ./a` to get clear error messages for this UB. `-Wall` tells us that `drawScreen` and `sand` return nothing when they're typed to return `int`. Change them to `void`.

I'd caution against scoping your loop control variables at the top of the function, which can lead to bugs. `drawScreen()` doesn't need `x` and `y` parameters. Those can be purely local.

Scoping the grid globally isn't ideal, either, but I'll leave it to preserve your original intent.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

const int size_x = 20;
const int size_y = 20;
const int alive = 1;
const int dead = 0;
int grid[20][20] = {
  {0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
};

void draw_screen() {
  system("cls");

  for (int y = 0; y < size_y; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < size_x; x++) {
      putc(grid[y][x] == alive ? '@' : ' ', stdout);
    }

    putc('\n', stdout);
  }
}

void simulate_sand(const int x, const int y) {
  // do nothing if dead or already at the bottom of the screen
  if (grid[y][x] == dead || y >= size_y - 1) {
    return;
  }
  // move down if empty
  else if (grid[y+1][x] == dead) {
    grid[y][x] = dead;
    grid[y+1][x] = alive;
  }
  // move down and left if empty
  else if (x > 0 && grid[y+1][x-1] == dead) {
    grid[y][x] = dead;
    grid[y+1][x-1] = alive;
  }
  // move down and right if empty
  else if (x < size_x - 1 && grid[y+1][x+1] == dead) {
    grid[y][x] = dead;
    grid[y+1][x+1] = alive;
  }
  // else do nothing; sand is resting on sand cells beneath it
}

int main(void) {
  for (int iterations = 0; iterations < 1000; iterations++) {
    for (int y = size_y - 1; y >= 0; y--) {
      for (int x = size_x - 1; x >= 0; x--) {
        simulate_sand(x, y);
      }
    }

    draw_screen();
  }
}
```